# Ajax not outputing input field of a web form in php loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a table and inside the table I have a button which brings down a web form for that row ID. The problem is 2 input text fields are not working when you submit the 2 or any other row the table.

My web form in for loop

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value='.$id.'>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eventInside" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="form-control sourceInside" type="url" placeholder="Type URL" />
</div>
<div>
   <input type="hidden" name="ID" value='.$id.'>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="Submit"  onclick=submit(this)>   
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block " onclick="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

My ajax request:

```
function submit(element){
var dive = $(element).closest('div');
          $.post(
 "submit.php/",
 {
     ID: $("[name=ID]",dive).val(),
     event: $("[name=eventInside]").val(),
     source: $(".sourceInside").val(),
},
```

In my ajax output I am getting the right ID for each row but not the event and source as they are coming empty in my ajax output. I tried getting the closest div of those input fields but still not working

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Don't duplicate the hidden input field, there is no reason to do that. Duplicating the name attribute creates a psuedo array of inputs that all have the same attribute value. Remove one of them.

Comment: Well you are not selecting the `eventInside` element based on the row like you do for the id. Is that the issue? I am not even sure how that even grabs the id with `dive` is the wrapping div around the button, not the form group.

Comment: @epascarello I see my problem now. Thank you